# How to animate translateX() on click

Tags: javascript, css

I am having an issue with translateX property.

I want the nav menu to be hidden on the right, and when the user clicks on the menu icon, the nav translateX from right to left with ease transition, of course th nav menu will be hidden before the click. it somehow doesn’t work, here is the code:

CSS:

```
/**************************************
    Desktop menu + menu icon
**************************************/
    #menu .nav-item {
      transform: translateX(85vh);
      display: none;
    }

    .clicked {
      display: block;
      transform: translateX(-85vh);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<header class="header">
    <!-- Navigation and logo -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <!-- navbar brand -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
            <img src="./imgs/rev_logo.png" />
        </a>
        <!-- toggle button -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span>
            <svg class="polygon-icon" viewBox="0 0 29.76 25.77">
              <polygon id="polygon" points="21.74 1 8.02 1 1.16 12.88 8.02 24.77 21.74 24.77 28.6 12.88 21.74 1"/>
            </svg>
          </span>
        </button>
        <!-- Menu -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="menu">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Explore</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Talks</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="speaker.php">Become a Speaker</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="host.php">Become a Host</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">News</a>
                </li>
              <li>
                <img class="desktop-menu-icon" src="./imgs/menu.svg" width="50" />
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".desktop-menu-icon").click(function(){
          $(".nav-item").addClass("clicked");
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add transition to the transform.

```
 #menu .nav-item {
  transform: translateX(85vh);
  display: none;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

See [this](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/transitions-and-transforms) article for more details on transitions and transforms